# Android 4.0 emulator crashes; Virtual Machine never finishes loaded OS on Mac

Tags: android, android-emulator, osx-snow-leopard, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am having an issue with the Android 4.0 virtual machine. I am on Mac OS 10.6 and using the Eclipse plug-in. Every time I try to start the virtual device, the loading screen comes up, but it never actually starts.

I left it alone for 30 minutes, and that did not help.

I have not had any trouble with 2.3.3 (Gingerbread) and the virtual machine. I set my target for the virtual machine to 4.0, and I gave ample memory (I think?) by using the default settings. I used the sdk manager to download and install everything I need, at least every update.

Here is what the console says; the first line looks worrysome:

```
[2011-11-05 21:47:40 - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring platform '.DS_Store', not a folder.

[2011-11-05 21:48:38 - SDK Manager] Updated AVD 'TestPhone2' based on Android 4.0, ARM (armeabi-v7a) processor,

[2011-11-05 21:48:38 - SDK Manager] with the following hardware config:

[2011-11-05 21:48:38 - SDK Manager] hw.lcd.density=160

[2011-11-05 21:48:38 - SDK Manager] hw.keyboard.lid=no

[2011-11-05 21:48:38 - SDK Manager] vm.heapSize=48             

[2011-11-05 21:48:38 - SDK Manager] hw.ramSize=512
```

The OS eventually slows, and kills the virtual machine. Any thoughts on how I can get this to work? For now I am moving back to 2.3.3 but I would really like to program for 4.0.

Comment: off-topic.  SO is only for programming questions.

Comment: @Sparky672: This question is so not-offtopic. How to correctly setting up the programming environment is just as important as how to correctly program, well, for a programmer.

Comment: @diwup, I did not say it was unimportant to programmers... I said it was off-topic on SO.  It's a question about software installation, not about programming... it's very clear-cut and likely will be closed soon.  These types of questions belong on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/faq)

Comment: Sparky672, it's absolutely NOT offtopic. Just read the FAQ: " if your question generally covers (...) - software tools commonly used by programmers (...) then you’re in the right place to ask your question!". http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: @David,  [Android Emulator questions go on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/search?q=android+emulator).

Comment: Ah, ok. You convinced me now. :-) But you gotta agree that the FAQ leaves margin to different interpretations.

Comment: @David, this comments section is not meant for this kind of discussion but you can get clarification at the [Meta Site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @Sparky672 No, there are 2200 android emulator questions here.  They do not belong on SU.

Comment: @Bill, and there are [nearly a thousand Android emulator questions at SU](http://superuser.com/search?q=android+emulator).  We don't typically discuss how to install/configure Mac applications on SO, do we?

Comment: @Sparky672 First, look at the results you're linking to.  A lot of those posts mention android, but not the emulator at all.  There are far fewer than 1000 android emulator questions on SU.  Second, if it's a programming tool that you're trying to install and configure on a Mac, go ahead and ask it here.  General applications questions go on SU.

Comment: @Bill, thanks Bill.  Please bear with me... are you saying I could ask, _"Why is Dreamweaver crashing?"_ and that too would be valid?  It seems to be more related to application or O/S issues than software development.

Comment: @Sparky672 Dreamweaver isn't exactly a tool specific to programming.  As a rule of thumb, if it's a tool that programmers are far more likely to have experience troubleshooting than your typical PC power user, then it's okay to ask about here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question over at SuperUser contains a similar problem description as yours. There's also an answer posted which may help you...

https://superuser.com/questions/74065/android-sdk-emulator-freezes-on-a-mac-running-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard

Comment: While this answer may theoretically answer the question, [it is better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @hichris123, Read the comments on the OP and you'll better understand why I intentionally posted the answer like this.

Comment: I actually did get here from the meta post... I'm just saying, even though it does have an answer on SU, why can't you just bring some of the content over to here, and provide the link as the reference? SE prefers to prevent link-only answers, even if it's just a link to another SE site...